# kubectl is not installed on GCE by default

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

Following the [guide](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/before-you-begin) I'm trying to manage Google Container Engine cluster from another machine on Google Compute Engine. Here is the output from my GCE instance:

```
oleksandr_berezianskyi_gmail_com@docker-managed-jenkins:~$ sudo gcloud components update preview
All components are up to date.
oleksandr_berezianskyi_gmail_com@docker-managed-jenkins:~$ sudo gcloud components update alpha
All components are up to date.
oleksandr_berezianskyi_gmail_com@docker-managed-jenkins:~$ gcloud alpha container kubectl create -f cassandra.yaml
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.container.kubectl) This command requires the kubernetes client (kubectl), which is installed with the gcloud preview component. Run 'gcloud components update preview', or make sure kubectl is installed somewhere on your
 path.
```

As you see my Google Cloud SDK seems to be up-to-date but still not working properly on GCE. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The correct way to install kubectl is now `gcloud components install kubectl`

- You must have the [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/#Quick_Start) installed
- For further information, [Quick Start Guide](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/quickstart)

Comment: where does this install the `kubectl` binary?

Comment: @Jatin in the bin folder where you installed the sdk

Answer (score 19):

If you have run `gcloud components update` that will install the kubectl binary on your system, it just won't be in your path. It will be located in the cloud-sdk install directory. You can add it to your path manually by running

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/share/google/google-cloud-sdk/bin/`

or you can create a symlink from a directory that is already in your path, like `/usr/local/bin` by running

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/google/google-cloud-sdk/bin/kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl`

Comment: Robert, could you please schedule a change to the output of the `gcloud alpha container kubectl create` because `Run 'gcloud components update preview'` is a bit missleading?

Comment: What version of gcloud are you running? The current version (0.9.61) now says `Run 'gcloud components update', or make sure kubectl is installed somewhere on your path.`.

Comment: I have the same message. The problem is that it is a little misleading. For me `or` in message means that running update should be enough. So I didn't even tried adding kubectl to path. So I would suggest to replace `or` with `also`

Comment: In my case, on Linux Mint 18, I had gcloud installed, installed kubectl with "gcloud components update kubectl", but still it was not available at the terminal. I created a symlink to /usr/bin/ and it worked

Comment: @RaduGabriel is gcloud in your path? If so, kubectl should be in your path as well.

Comment: @RobertBailey  After I upgraded my OS from Linux Mint 17.3 to 18, glcoud was still working fine, while kubectl was was removed. I installed kubectl with: "gcloud components update kubectl". After installation I was not able to use kubectl on the terminal, so I followed your suggestion and created a symlink. It worked fine after that.

Comment: On MacOS, if you installed `google-cloud-sdk` using `brew cask install google-cloud-sdk`, sdk's `bin` directory will be located in `/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/bin/`

Answer (score 2):

System Version: macOS 13.1 (22C65)
Chip: Apple M1
ProductVersion:     13.1

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/bin/
```

helped me

Answer (score 1):

You can download the current version of the kubectl binary from this Google Cloud Storage URL: https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v0.18.2/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl

Answer (score 1):

As of (at least) 138.0.0 (Nov 2016)

It's now `gcloud components install kubectl`

This is when running:

`Your current Cloud SDK version is: 138.0.0`

Here are the related instructions:

```
To install or remove components at your current SDK version [138.0.0], run:
  $ gcloud components install COMPONENT_ID
  $ gcloud components remove COMPONENT_ID

To update your SDK installation to the latest version [141.0.0], run:
  $ gcloud components update
```

Comment: Daniel thanks for this answer. Can you include documentation on what version of GCE you are referencing so that this answer will last over time and be understood at a much later date?